# Rest template result is getting null in api call in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using below code to call remote API to remove user id(http://localhost:8080/remove).

```
try {
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    final UriComponentsBuilder builder = 
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);
    builder.queryParam("acdc_id", acdcId);
ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> result =
            restTemplate.exchange(
                builder.toUriString(),
                HttpMethod.DELETE,
                null,
                ServiceResponse.class);
}catch(Exception e){
//exception handling
}
```

Remote API return 200 http code for success flow(working fine), but when some user id will not available then API sent below custom response:

```
{
"error code": "404",
"error": "USER ID Node not found : xyz"
}
```

I have already ServiceResponse.java class to get above response, but Rest Template returning below error in this case.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 null
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
```

My ServiceResponse class is,

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ServiceResponse {

@JsonProperty(value = "error code")
private String errorCode;

@JsonProperty(value = "error")
private String error;

/**
 * @return the error.
 */
public String getError() {
    return error;
}

/**
 * @param error The error to set.
 */
public void setError(final String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

/**
 * @return the errorCode.
 */
public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

/**
 * @param errorCode The errorCode to set.
 */
public void setErrorCode(final String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}

}
```

Could you please help me here to fix my issue, or provide any suggestion, how I can get proper response from API instead null error

Comment: If the user is not found, 404 it's the correct answer. I ask you some clarifications: is the API you're calling that returns 404? Can you add the complete code of controllers of both applications?

Comment: @A.Wolf, yes it is correct.

Comment: So you're trying to call the API from another web service? Where you catch the result is another API and that API returns 200?

Comment: I am not sure but response keys should not have space. In your example there is space in "error code".

Comment: Yes API return 200 in result.getStatusCodeValue() if user Id removed successfully, but if user id not available, it return custom error response and due to this custom response from api, rest template throwing exception, instead of populating it in ServiceResponse class

Comment: You should convert the error respone to your preferred class in catch block. You should catch HttpClientErrorException

Comment: I want know one thing, why RestTemplate throw exception and does not catch 404 in result.getStatusCodeValue() method as like 200 http status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873432/rest-template-result-is-getting-null-in-api-call-in-spring-boot/59873729#comment105877666_59873432), you're getting HttpClientErrorException, which should be caught and dealt with. You're catching the whole Exception class, but there is no code in it. Or you can use @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler together to achieve this as well.

Comment: Can we catch Json string as well, with 404 status code in Exception Handling? Because in case of service unavailable or user id not found , this both cases I have different logic at client side. Due to HttpClientErrorException, I am not able to find whether it is service unavailable or user id not found.

Comment: I assume you're asking how to read the response object when you catch HttpClientErrorException. You can do this: `catch (HttpClientErrorException hse) {
            String responseBody = hse.getResponseBodyAsString();
            log.error("Exception response is {}", responseBody );
            //do something with responseBody 
        }`

Comment: Perfect!! Above suggestion worked for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Controller Advice `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to handle the exceptions . You can send Custom response from the method. You can define exceptionHandler for HttpClientErrorException and send custom response from this method.

Please check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_exception_handling.htm for further details.

One more option is you can use CustomResponseErrorHandler something like below

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler 
  implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) 
      throws IOException {

        return (
          httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == CLIENT_ERROR 
          || httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) 
      throws IOException {

        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode()
          .series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR) {
            // handle SERVER_ERROR
        } else if (httpResponse.getStatusCode()
          .series() == HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR) {
            // handle CLIENT_ERROR
            if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
                throw new NotFoundException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
@Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler());

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Please check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling for ResponseErrorHandler

Comment: Instead of handling exception why rest template does not catch 404 http status code in result.getStatusCodeValue() method as like 200 http status code after response from remote api?

Comment: @AnkushNagapure i have updated my answer. You can use RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler to handle exception.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion,But My remote API responding below json with 404 http status code, if user id not available at service side:                                                                            {
"error code": "404",
"error": "USER ID not found : xyz"
}     and if service is unavailable, remote api responding with 404 Http status code. So in both case it throwing  HttpClientErrorException. Because of this I am not able to find if service is unavailable or user id not found. I have different logic in this both case. So I was I asking why RestTemlate does not catch Json if 404.

Comment: @AnkushNagapure If the service is not available then 404 is not the correct status. 404 is resource not found status. Also when you when you get HttpStatus code 404 then you can have custom logic and use it accordingly. By the way you question didn't suggest what are you asking for now.